# Removing panel from JTabbedPane via button on panel

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have 2 classes, mainFrame and panel. By clicking the button on mainFrame I call panel from another class and set it in tabbed pane which is in JFrame (mainFrame class). Now, I have another button (btnRemove) on my panel in panel class. So when I click that button I want to remove my panel from tabbed pane in mainFrame class. How do I write my listener properly?

mainFrame class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
JTabbedPane tPane = new JTabbedPane();
JButton btn = new JButton("Add panel");
public MainFrame(){
    setSize(400,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(tPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(btn,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            panel p = new panel();
            tPane.add("Panel",p);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new MainFrame();
}
}
```

panel class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Panel extends JPanel{
JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove panel");

public Panel(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(btnRemove);
    btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the panel,, or the entire tab?  BTW - 1) Don't extend `JFrame` or `JPanel` - instead have a frame instance, and a method to produce the `JPanel` 2) Don't call `setSize()` 3) Use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` 4) Don't call `setVisible(true)` until after the components are added and `pack()` is called. 5) A GUI should be created and altered on the EDT. 6) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
panel.this.getParent().remove(panel.this);
```

If you want the code to keep working even if you nest the button inside a sub-panel, you should use the follwoing:

```
SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JTabbedPane.class, panel.this).remove(panel.this);
```

Side note: please respect Java naming conventions: classes start with upper-case letters.

Comment: @brano88: Standards benefit you by making code more readable, hence easier to review critically.

Comment: +1 but to avoiding stonesedges, have look at [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html)

Comment: @mKorbel: you're right. I've edited my answer (I guess that's what you has in mind)